# OUYA SDK on desktop

Tags: android, ouya

Is there a way to get and run OUYA's operating system/environment/whatever you want to call it on the desktop? By that I primarily mean within a simulator of any sort (e.g. Android's variant of qemu would be okay too).

Is the OUYA software even openly available for download?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ouya ODK is available and free.  You should follow the Ouya developer documents for a [walk-through of setting up your Ouya development environment](https://devs.ouya.tv/developers/docs/setup).  It tells you where to find  and configure everything.

Once you have your development environment set up, you can create a Android virtual device (AVD) that closely resembles the Ouya.  This procedure is also described in the aforementioned document. (It is also trivial test your project on an actual Ouya device, if you have one handy.)

Comment: Thanks! That's the information I received via other channels as well. I'll accept this as the best answer, despite this being an extremely substandard substitute for a proper simulated environment. Let me elaborate in a separate comment.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something :-) this in no way allows me to test the launcher, or the controller API unless I have a physical device. I have tried installing the framework and the launcher inside both Android's fork of Qemu and inside AndroVM in VirtualBox; in both cases there is an expectation that I'll connect the OUYA controller via Bluetooth (no idea how I'm expected to do that inside an emulator except by attaching an extra Bluetooth dongle, and even then without an OUYA controller), and not as a USB HID device.

Comment: Looks like I had to create a "keyboard" layout file for my Android-unsupported joystick and put it in `/system/usr/keylayouts`. Then OUYA launcher accepted the keys. Figuring this out was NOT my idea of a well-spent afternoon… Of course -- now the launcher in AndroVM can't find the servers. Oh the humanity… :/

Comment: I agree that the Ouya docs are not great (yet?).  They definitely slant toward developers with physical devices to test on.  It sounds like you're making virtual progress, though. :)